# How do you change the width of this div?

Tags: jquery, html

I want the width of the div to be the same as the 'iframe' currently it makes the width of the div a lot bigger!

Thanks in advance

```
<div id="box3" onmouseup="$('#box3').stop().animate({boxShadow: '10px 10px 15px', top: 0}, 'fast')" 
onmousedown="$('#box3').stop().animate({boxShadow: '3px 3px 3px', top: 3}, 'fast')" style="top: 0px;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px 0px rgb(102, 102, 102);">
<iframe width="700" height="525" id="SHADDOW" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/LRo-L9zYf-M" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Edit the `style` attribute of the `div` to include `width=700px`, or something similar.

Comment: Wow that was dumb of me. In my defense I swear I did try that! any way thanks a lot Lorax!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe too obvious, but just make it the same width as the iframe:

```
#box3 { width : 700px; }
```

Another possible option:

```
#box3 { float : left; }
```

`float:left` may have "side effects" that you don't want, but you won't have to concern yourself with the width of the content.

Aside: I would highly suggest moving your script and CSS *out* of HTML attributes and into external CSS and javaScript files. Code like that is very hard to maintain.

Comment: +1 for moving the CSS and JavaScript out of the HTML.

Comment: Imagine a whole page with code like that. Gives me nightmares. Throw in some inline PHP and SQL queries and you got some top-notch spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

use this script :

```
<script>
$(function(){
$("#box3").css("width",$("#SHADDOW").css("width"));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="box3" onmouseup="$('#box3').stop().animate({boxShadow: '10px 10px 15px', top: 0}, 'fast')" onmousedown="$('#box3').stop().animate({boxShadow: '3px 3px 3px', top: 3}, 'fast')" style="top: 0px;
width: 700px;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px 0px rgb(102, 102, 102);">
<iframe width="700" height="525" id="SHADDOW" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/LRo-L9zYf-M" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
</div>
```